# NullReferenceException occurred in Caliburn.Micro.dll

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF Caliburn.Micro application. Here is a part of my code:

```
  protected override void OnViewLoaded( object view )
  {
     base.OnViewLoaded( view );

     var firstDataEntryVM = new FirstDataEntryViewModel();
     ActivateItem(firstDataEntryVM);
```

This causes

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Caliburn.Micro.dll
```

Here is the call stack:

[image]

I downloaded source code of Caliburn.Micro.WPF and added it to the solution. But now I cannot run the application at all:

[image]

How can I debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways come to mind:

- Do you have the source code where the error is happening (I haven't looked to see if Caliburn is open source)?
- Decompile the code and recompile it into a project using a decompiler such as [Just Decompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx).
- [Intellitrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) can give you some additional information.

**EDIT**
The source code for this project is available at [CodePlex](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/).  Download the code and debug from Visual Studio!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added Calirubn.Micro.WPF project to my solution, and added a reference to it. But the application crashes in the BootStrapper's GetInstance(). See the picture in my edited question.

Comment: You might need to copy the Calirubn.Micro.dll to your the \bin\debug (or similar) output directory of the host application.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to activate the `FirstDataEntryViewModel` too early. Try to do it in `OnInitialize` or `OnActivate` method. Note that the latter is invoked every time the view model is activated.